# NPM error while building Elixir/Phoenix code using Gitlab CI Pipe

Tags: npm, elixir, gitlab-ci

We are building and deploying our Elixir/Phoenix code using Gitlab CI pipe.

Everything was working perfectly fine but today our build log started throwing npm errors and not being able to build the code further

Getting below error in our build logs

```
#21 1.039 npm ERR! dot-prop not accessible from stylehacks:postcss-selector-parser
852#21 1.044 
853#21 1.044 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
854#21 1.045 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-18T00_00_39_802Z-debug.log
855#21 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm --prefix ./assets ci --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error]: exit code: 1
856------
857 > [build 12/17] RUN npm --prefix ./assets ci --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error:
858------
859executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm --prefix ./assets ci --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error]: exit code: 1

860
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
861ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

We even tried updating our postcss package but no luck

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: The content of `/root/.npm/_logs/2021-12-18T00_00_39_802Z-debug.log` would be of great help here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We could get it working for now by changing RUN npm --prefix ./assets ci --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error to RUN npm --prefix ./assets install --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error

Will close the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to fix the build issue by modifying the command for npm

Changed code line

From

```
RUN npm --prefix ./assets ci --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error
```

to

```
RUN npm --prefix ./assets install --progress=false --no-audit --loglevel=error
```